# Unable to open/read large sized excel file (.xlsx) of size>110MB

Tags: excel, api, uipath, uipath-activity

I downloaded a excel file (.xlsx) of size>110MB using API (http request) and tried to read the file using workboook read range and Excel application scope read range activity in Uipath. but I get error that 'file has corrupted data'. I tried a custom activity from marketplace as well. I am unable to open the file even manually.  Can someone help

Comment: Which API you mean?

Comment: Did you try to open it with a Notebook? If the data is tabular, maybe you can read it. Anyways, 110 MB for an Excel file is huge...